# CodeIgniter Pagination Problem

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using codeigniter and its pagination class. It works perfectly and it looks something like this:

> « First  < **1** 2 3 4 5 >  Last »

Here is my code:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'controlpanel/';
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['total_rows'] = $count;
$config['per_page'] = '3'; 
$this->pagination->initialize($config); 
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->load->view('controlpanel', $data);
```

I have this in my routes:

```
$route['controlpanel/(:num)'] = "controlpanel/index/$1";
```

However, whenever I get to a differentpage i.e. `controlpanel/3` - the number 1 is always bold - it should change to 2 or 3 etc!

Why doesn't it?

When I change the `$config['base_url']` to `base_url().'controlpanel/page'` then does the pagination work correctly by boldening the correct number - but the link 1 points to the URL `controlpanel/page` which is the wrong page for me as the base is just `controlpanel`.

Thanks all for any help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The pagination class should check the second parameter, not the third(default).

Add this to the config array to change this:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = '2';
```

---

This won't change anything but be helpful in creating the url needed.
change this :

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'controlpanel/';
```

to this:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('controlpanel');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Thorpe - I tried the above and the same thing happened. Are you saying per_page is the segment of the URL that the pagination class will check?? Btw, I am using a htaccess file that just removes the index.php part.

Comment: I think you meant `$config['uri_segment'] = 2;` I have added this and it works! Please edit your question so others can see it more easily. Your answer sparked a thought in what was needed thank you very much. I didn't realise how the pagination class was getting the page number it needs to go to!

Comment: no problem. I figured the error and edited it a while ago. :)

Comment: Thanks for this, it fixed my issue. I remembered to use the segment in the model, but forgot to use it in the pagination settings as well, appreciate it!

Comment: I have wrote tutorial about Cdeigniter Pagination. Please have a look and give your suggestions https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 2):

Also dont forget to check out for..
$inboxMessageCount this value set from the controller

$config['total_rows'] = $inboxMessageCount;

If this value set, is less than the limit value, then  pagination will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Also put  this line

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$config['first_tag_open']  = '<li>';

$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['first_url'] = site_url('your controller url');
```

put `$config['first_url']` like this to make working of your first tag url