# codeigniter pagination: create links

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this piece of code, which uses Codeigniter's native Pagination Class.

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'notification/display_notification_info/'.$notification_id;
            $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
            $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

It shows the last page by default. So, the links are displayed like so:

```
< 1, 2, 3
```

It doesn't show the last page's URL.
It should be:

```
 base_url/3
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: what is the total row count? and how many links are generated?

Comment: You can reference this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330550/codeigniter-pagination-problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101513/how-to-create-pagination-in-codeiginter/23109383#23109383

Answer (score 0):

If your actual page is your last page by default, then it will not show a URL.
But you can still to force it [url to current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842689/url-for-first-number-page-in-codeigniter-pagination)

Answer (score 0):

is the url correctly formed (yourdomain.com/notification/display_notification_info/'.$notification_id)?
don't use base_url()..use site_url() 
try it

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('notification/display_notification_info/'.$notification_id);
```