# How to create Pagination in Codeiginter?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I am new to codeigniter, I am trying to create pagination on the records i am fetching from database. I have written the following code, its showing me pagination but its not effecting the result set, I still have all the records on the same page and when i click on  `Page2` it says `no page found`.

Kindly guide me how to create pagination?

**MODEL**

```
public function students_list()
{


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('student'); 

    $this->db->limit($limit,$start);                

    $query= $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function all_students()
{

    //Pagination    
            $this->load->library('pagination');

            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'mycontroller/all_students/';
            $config['total_rows'] = 200;
            $config['per_page'] = 5;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            echo $this->pagination->create_links(); 

    //Pagination

    $this->load->model('loginmodel');
    $data['students_data']= $this->loginmodel->students_list();
    $data['dropdown']=      $this->loginmodel->get_degree_names();

    $this->load->view('all_students', $data);

}
```

**VIEW**

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'sidebar.php';


$this->pagination->create_links();
?>
<?php 

foreach($students_data as $teachers_records)
{
    ...
     ....
```

Comment: lots of quetion already in stack about pagination

Comment: I have checked most of them, but still unable to understand why its not working here

Comment: i just give an example and convert according to your answer

Comment: In your code you not set limit to generate pagination

Comment: please rewrite according to my answer

Comment: @user3480644 Answer kittiyallo?

Answer (score 2):

Controller:

```
public function all_students() 
 {      $this->load->model('loginmodel');
        $config['anchor_class'] = '';
        $config['show_count'] = true;
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('controllername/all_students');
        $config['total_rows'] = sizeof($this->loginmodel->students_list());

        $data['students_data']= $this->loginmodel->students_list();
        $data['dropdown']=      $this->loginmodel->get_degree_names();
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $this->jquery_pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['links'] = $this->jquery_pagination->create_links();
        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data['details'] = $this->loginmodel->students_list($config['per_page'], $data['page']);
        $this->load->view('all_students', $data);
    }
```

Model

```
public function students_list($limit=NULL,$start=NULL)
{


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('student'); 

    $this->db->limit($limit,$start);                

    $query= $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..I have replaced my code with your code, Now its giving me the following error message in my `Model` 
`A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: start

Filename: models/loginmodel.php

Line Number: 582`

Comment: I have added the Model code in my question...Kindly check it

Comment: The error is still there .. 
`A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Loginmodel::students_list(), called in F:\xampp\htdocs\University\application\controllers\mycontroller.php on line 613 and defined

Filename: models/loginmodel.php

Line Number: 590
`

Comment: slight change in model function

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal why you querying two times in controller? i suggest to take it on a variable the use it. and also sizeof return the total of the current result .. not the all rows in tables

Comment: First it was giving me the following error message, `
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Mycontroller::$jquery_pagination

Filename: controllers/mycontroller.php

Line Number: 620
`

Comment: But when i replace `jquery_pagination` with `pagination` its working fine..Now its not displaying any error message but it also not displaying any result.

Comment: Thats ur view page problem

Answer (score 1):

you need to some data to displat in pagination use query for this and `$config['total_rows']` so it will display total result pagination with 5 records

in my case i am using `$this->Account->search_users($where,false, false,false,true,false);` is a model function will return array of result

```
return $query->result_array();
```

controller :-

```
      $this->load->library('pagination');   
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Account->search_users($where,false, false,false,true,false);
    $config['per_page']= 5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['base_url']= base_url().'/app/index'; 
    $config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&"); 
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->data['paginglinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();     
    $this->data['per_page'] = $this->uri->segment(3);       
    $this->data['offset'] = $offset ;
```

view:-

```
<div class="pagination" style="float:right;"> <?php echo $paginglinks; ?></div>
```

For more info :- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

my model function is :-

```
public function search_users($where = false, $num = false, $offset = false, $order_by = false, $count = false, $select = false , $table=false){

    if(!$select){$select = 'U.*';}

        if(isset($where['where']) && !empty($where['where'])) {
            $this->db->where($where['where']);
        }

        if($order_by){
            $this->db->order_by($order_by[0], $order_by[1]);
        }else{
            $this->db->order_by('U.u_id', 'DESC');
        }

        $query = $this->db->get($table . ' AS U');
        //print_r($this->db->last_query()).'<hr>';
        $recount = $query->num_rows;    
        if($count) {
            return $recount;    
        }

        if($recount > 0){
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else{ 
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a better use of pagination create a function in your helper. That will very useful for you for future use. you don't ever need to load library and other values. 
fix this function in your helper.

```
if( ! function_exists('createPaginationForm')) {
    function createPaginationForm($url, $totalRows, $perPage, $segment, $queryString = '', $config = array()) {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().$url;
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
        $config['per_page'] = $perPage;
        $config['uri_segment'] = $segment;
        $CI->pagination->initialize($config);
        return $CI->pagination->create_links($queryString);
    }
}
```

and use in your controller .

```
var $perPage = '10';
var $segment = '4';
$total_result = "50";
$pagination = createPaginationForm('admin/news/index/',$total_result ,$this->perPage, $this->segment);
$this->data['pagination'] = $pagination;
```

and print this in your view.

```
echo $pagination
```

Answer (score 1):

First Of All i suggest to create a helper function to configure your pagination like this. You gotta find out from codeigniter documention for the option purpose in config

```
if (!function_exists('getPaginationConfig')) {
    function getPaginationConfig($url,$total_row,$per_page,$num_links=3){
            $config = array();
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;// depends on how you passing your page number
            $config['base_url'] = $url;
            $config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
            $config['per_page'] = $per_page; 
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul>';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['first_link'] = '&lt;&lt;';
            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['last_link'] = '&gt;&gt;';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['num_links'] = $num_links;

     return $config;        
   }
}
```

Now On Controller .. you need to get total rows from database and set the perpage in pagination 
and call with the config
here is an example of controller function

```
 function getMyList($page){
        $limit = YOUR_PAGE_LIMIT;//may be some global variable or input from frontend
        $starting = ($page-1)*$limit;

        $data['results']  = $this->your_model->getListOfTable($where,$limit,$starting);
        $total_rows = $this->your_model->getTotalRowsOfTable($where);// where is filter condition

        $this -> load -> helper('your_helper');// where yours getPaginationConfig is defined
        $this -> load -> library('pagination');
        $this -> pagination -> initialize(getPaginationConfig(site_url('controller/function'), $total_rows,$limit));
        $data['pagination'] = $this -> pagination -> create_links();
        $this->load->view('yourview',$data);
```

Your model may look like this

```
function getListOfTable($where = array(), $limit, $starting = 0) {
        $this -> db -> select('*');
        // <-- There is never any reason to write this line!
        $this -> db -> from('your_tables');
        if (!empty($where))
           $this -> db -> where($where);
        $this -> db -> limit($limit, $starting);
        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        if ($query -> num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query -> result();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

function getTotalRowsOfTable($where = array()){
    if (!empty($data))
         $this -> db -> where($where);
    $this -> db -> from('your_table');
    return $this -> db -> count_all_results();

}
```

Now On View you just need to echo the pagination where you like

```
  <div id="pagination"><?php echo $pagination;?></div>
```